# Uno ILoggerFactory does not contain definition AddConsole

Tags: build, uno-platform

I am attempting to build a uno-platform app and, immediately, I get an error

```
Error CS1929 'ILoggerFactory' does not contain a definition for 'AddConsole' 
and the best extension method overload 'ConsoleLoggerExtensions.AddConsole(ILoggingBuilder, 
Action<ConsoleLoggerOptions>)' requires a receiver of type 'ILoggingBuilder'    
UnoTest.Droid, UnoTest.UWP, UnoTest.Wasm, UnoTest.iOS, UnoTest.macOS
```

I have package microsoft.extensions.logging.console version 5.0.0 installed, as well as microsoft.extensions.logging.filter version 1.1.2.

And the source code does have `using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;`

I have the suspicion that there may be some backwards compatibility issue with the referenced API.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Uno Platform isn't compatible with versions of `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console` above 1.1.1. The reason is that later versions use threading APIs which currently don't function on WebAssembly (which is single-threaded only).

If possible, downgrade the installed versions of `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console` and `Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Filter` to 1.1.1.